# add action / item to custom titlebar in android

Tags: android

I have been trying for 2 days to add actions to the title/action bar in my android app. I have started the app to learn android and familiarize myself

I have read a couple of question on stackoverflow and some other tutorials on google to try and find a answer, I couldn't however find one for a custom title bar but rather a title bar in general.

What I have tried is adding the following in my activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case ADD_NEW_FRIEND_ID: {
        Intent i = new Intent(FriendList.this, AddFriend.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

But nothing happens. Any suggestions on where to go from here or what to do?

Comment: What is "a custom title bar"? Where is this `onMenuItemSelected()` method coming from that you are overriding, since there is no such method in Android?

Comment: Are you adding the items in oncreateoptionsmenu?

Comment: @Lesleh I added that part to the main post

Comment: @CommonsWare I actually found that part on multiple threads and used it. The custom titlebar is a class that was created to style the titlebar/actionbar to be dynamic per user that's logged in to the app, and is set here:
    `CommonUtility.setCustomTitlebar(FriendList.this, imService);
   ownusername = imService.getUsername();`

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `onMenuItemSelected()` in Android, perhaps try `onOptionsItemSelected()`, to line up with your `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Also, since you are trying to "learn android and familiarize myself", I would recommend getting rid of the "class that was created to style the titlebar/actionbar to be dynamic per user that's logged in to the app". While that may be a nice feature, it will add unnecessary complexity to your app and may interfere with your learning experience. Focus on learning *Android* first, then fret about customizable title bars later.

Comment: Thank you.. I replaced the code with the ones you mentioned above, but yields me the exact same results. When the devices hardware "Menu" button is pressed, it brings up a menu from the bottom which is great and all, but wouldn't work with a device without a hardware "menu" button. I would like to get that on the top instead in the action/title bar.

Comment: @ShaunJansenVanNieuwenhuizen: "I would like to get that on the top instead in the action/title bar" -- you will have to implement your own menu system from scratch. `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and kin are tied to the action bar. It *happens* to still work even if you disable the action bar, on devices with a MENU button. However, if you are going to replace the action bar, you will need to create your own menu engine.